# LUCENE and Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, lucene

i am using lucene for providing indexing and searching on text file.can i use HDFS for storing index file.

Answer (score 2):

You interchange tasks: instead of thinking where to use Hadoop, first think what you need to implement your project. And if you see that you need Hadoop, it will become obvious where and how to use it.

One tip. Most probably you don't need neither Hadoop, nor even Lucene itself: [**Solr**](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) - search server created on top of Lucene - now has distributed setup, which is specifically designed for indexing and searching; [**Nutch**](http://nutch.apache.org/) may be used as front-end for Solr to crawl the web; and [**Tika**](http://tika.apache.org/) may help you to parse all types of offline files.

Comment: Looks like he needs to M.Tech project where he might have to use Hadoop ; or wants to use hadoop anyhow so as to put on his resume *smiles*

Comment: I have desktop data in text file .also i will fetch data from social networking sites in text form not in images,audio or video. Now i want to use hadoop for distribute indexing and searching task across different nodes. my aim is to learn hadoop and give new framework for indexing and searching using lucene.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene comes into picture after all your data is ready in form of lucene documents ( lucene cache ).
Looks like you know Lucene already. The purpose of Hadoop is to reduce a big task into small chunks. I think first usage of Hadoop can be to gather data. Each hadoop node can keep collecting data; and create lucene documents

Comment: I have desktop data in text file .also i will fetch data from social networking sites in text form not in images,audio or video. Now i want to use hadoop for distribute indexing and searching task across different nodes. my aim is to learn hadoop and give new framework for indexing and searching using lucene.